# Changed ProgressBar color in XAML, now animation is gone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, progress-bar

I successfully changed the color of my determinate progress bar in the XAML like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="Foreground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA5C5D1" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BFA5C5D1" Offset="0.052"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BFA5C5D1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#F2A5C5D1" Offset="0.937"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#66D8D8D8" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#7FC1C1C1" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#72CFCFCF" Offset="0.721"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#66DCDCDC" Offset="0.499"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#66EAEAEA" Offset="0.068"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="1">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="opacityMask" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0"/>
                        <Grid Margin="-1">
                            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask}"/>
                            </Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" RadiusX="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask, Path=RadiusX}" RadiusY="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask, Path=RadiusY}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" RadiusX="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask, Path=RadiusX}" RadiusY="{Binding ElementName=opacityMask, Path=RadiusY}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

However, I would like the bar to keep it's glowing animation that it had before I changed the style. Currently there is no animation happening at all when I set IsDeterminate="True"; it just sits static filled with the foreground color I specified in the XAML.

How can I get the animation back?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing story boar in control template. Here is default template from MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change color then please override this

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorButtonFaceColor}" />
```

or if you want to change other things as well

```
<Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Updating" To="Determinate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <RepositionThemeAnimation TargetName="ProgressBarIndicator" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.IndicatorLengthDelta}" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="Paused" To="Determinate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressBarIndicator"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition From="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="EllipseGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Updating" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseGrid"
                                                     Duration="0:0:3.917"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                     From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.ContainerAnimationStartPosition}"
                                                     To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.ContainerAnimationEndPosition}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="E1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationEndPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="E2">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.167" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.167" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.167" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.167" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationEndPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="E3">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.333" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.333" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.333" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationEndPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="E4">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.5" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationEndPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="E5">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.667" Value="0" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.667" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.667" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationWellPosition}" />
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.667" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseAnimationEndPosition}" KeySpline="0.4,0,0.6,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="B1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-50" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="100" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="B2">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-50" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.667" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.167" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.167" Value="100" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="B3">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-50" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.833" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.333" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.333" Value="100" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="B4">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-50" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.5" Value="100" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="B5">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-50" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.167" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.667" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.667" Value="100" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseGrid"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="E1"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="E2"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="E3"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="E4"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="E5"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!-- Both FadeOutThemeAnimation and a DoubleAnimation on Opacity are necessary
                                         here.  The FadeOutThemeAnimation is necessary in the Indeterminate state so
                                         that we can do a FadeInThemeAnimation when transitioning back to the
                                         Determinate state.  The DoubleAnimation on Opacity is necessary to hide the
                                         DeterminateRoot immediately so that it does not slowly fade out during each
                                         iteration of the Indeterminate state animation. -->
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="DeterminateRoot" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="0"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="E1">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="E2">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.167" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.167" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.167" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.167" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="E3">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.333" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.333" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.333" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="E4">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.5" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.5" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="E5">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.667" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.667" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.667" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.667" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Error">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressBarIndicator">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Paused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ProgressBarIndicator"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="0.5"
                                                     Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="EllipseGrid"
                          Opacity="0">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="B1"
                                Grid.Column="8"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="E1"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="7"
                                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}" />
                        <Border x:Name="B2"
                                Grid.Column="6"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="E2"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="5"
                                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}" />
                        <Border x:Name="B3"
                                Grid.Column="4"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="E3"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="3"
                                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}" />
                        <Border x:Name="B4"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="E4"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                                   Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseOffset}" />
                        <Border x:Name="B5"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="E5"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.EllipseDiameter}"
                                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="DeterminateRoot"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```